# How to save sessions outside of webroot;

Tags: php

I am trying to save sessions outside of the web root. my website root folder is

```
public_html -> example.com
```

The sessions folder i have created is a sibling of the public_html folder. I don't know how to reach it.  I tried below but i get an error.

```
session.save_path = /sessions;
```

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you give needs to be in quotes; that may be all that's wrong here:

```
session.save_path = "/sessions"
```

You mentioned that "the sessions folder is a sibling of public_html" so I'm assuming that `public_html` is actually at the top-level of your filesystem. This would be unusual, though. Are you sure there is not more to the path? (You can double check by running `pwd -P` while in the directory, if you're using a UNIX-like system. You'll get back the full path to the directory.)

You also don't need a semicolon. That semicolon makes me a little wary, though: are you adding that configuration to your `php.ini` file? It's not something you'd add to just any piece of PHP code.

If you don't have access to `php.ini` and still need to change the save path, see [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) in the manual.

Comment: i added quotes and i get this error "Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct ('/sessions') in Unknown on line 0" and this error "Warning: Unknown: open(/sessions/sess_c27b6fdadf4637b9a7a16ddee6d33bef, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in"

Comment: Did you check the physical path as I suggested? I have never seen a top-level `/sessions` directory before, so I'm very skeptical that's really what you have.

Comment: where do you suggest i put the sessions folder?  In the public_html folder?  Because the public_html folder is the web root.. So i putting the /sessions folder on the same level as public_html is outside the webroot